# AWS EC2 - Run persistent Python Script on Start-Up (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to lower my AWS costs by starting and stopping my instances when I do not need them. Currently I have lambda triggers with CloudWatch that start/stop and this part is working.

However I now need to be able to boot with the lambda and begin running my python script automatically (it loops forever - until the next lambda closes the instance).

I've tried both the `/rc.local` method and the `crontab` method and have had zero luck so far and am having a hard time even debugging what is going wrong because I get no output/feedback.

- What is the current best practice and **easiest** way to get a python script to run on start-up?
- **I also need it to run persistently in EC2 without an active SSH.** I usually set my scripts to run in tmux to achieve this so not sure how to handle it here.

My python path is `~/myenv/bin/python3` and the file is in `~/scripts/myscript.py`.

I am running ubuntu 16.04.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What does your script do? Have you tried absolute path in `rc.local`? Have you tired manually run `rc.local` by `bash rc.local` or `sh rc.local` as `root`?

Comment: It's a lengthy script to ETL data into redshift. Manually running `rc.local` worked just then. Curiously it restarts itself when I ctrl+C out of it, normal behaviour?

Comment: It would be better if you create a service for your script using `systemd`. That's the best practice on Ubuntu 16.04.